# Сколько генерируется FCM токен? В каких случаях его получение невозможно? В каких случаях он выдается заново?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messages

Я не знаю стоит ли мне задавать все три вопроса в 1 "теме", но попробую.

**1) Сколько генерируется FCM токен?**
В текущем приложении получение FCM токена является обязательным условием его работы, поэтому в самом начале я пытаюсь его получить с помощью команды

```
String fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Первое но. Для его генерации необходимо некоторое время (как пишут в зарубежных источниках - "обычно менее 10 секунд, в зависимости от интернета, загруженности устройства и т. п."). Таким образом мне придется запускать поток, который будет каждые N секунд проверять наличие токена и если он получен, то продолжать работу приложения, что мне кажется... ну неправильным, хотя другого способа я не вижу.

К слову, как я уже сказал - работа приложения без него невозможно, посему хотелось бы узнать, можно ли его чем то заменить в случае отсутствия (кроме постоянного соединения с сервером).

**2) В каких случаях его получение невозможно?**
Второе но. Для его создания есть несколько условий, известные мне - наличие на устройстве google-play-services, а так же интернет-соединения. Окончательный ли это список или есть еще какие-либо зависимости/условия?

**3) В каких случаях он выдается заново?**
Функция, отвечающая за получение токена в сервисе называется

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {}
```

Название функции мягко говоря намекает на то, что может быть выдан новый FCM (да и зачем вообще целый сервис для получения токена, FirebaseInstanceIdService). В каких случаях это может произойти? Возможно, название функции вводит меня в заблуждение?

Comment: при удалении приложения токен меняется